# How two merge two Data Frames in pandas having two different Dates belonging to same week ? dates of df1 should come in Final Table

Tags: python, pandas

df1=

| Date | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| 18-01-2022 | 'abc' |
| 15-02-2022 | 'xyz' |

df2=

| Date | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| 22-01-2022 | 11 |
| 18-02-2022 | 15 |

so that output looks like ---

| Date | Brand | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18-01-2022 | 'abc' | 11 |
| 15-02-2022 | 'xyz' | 15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `Date` to a week period and merge using that, and clean up the final data (i.e. drop extra columns)

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-01-18', '2022-02-15'], 'Brand': ['abc', 'xyz']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-01-22', '2022-02-18'], 'Qty': [11, 15]})

df1['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date).dt.to_period('W')
df2['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date).dt.to_period('W')

df1.merge(df2[['week', 'Qty']], on='week').drop(['week'], axis=1)
```

this produces output:

```
         Date Brand  Qty
0  2022-01-18   abc   11
1  2022-02-15   xyz   15
```